# cmake generated header causes double build

Tags: c++, cmake, ninja

A very simple scenario - I need to generate header, include it and if generated header is updated while cmake build, all dependent cpp units also must be rebuilt.

A simplified example:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.h
    COMMAND ...
    DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.in"

add_custom_target(test_target DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.h)

add_executable(test_exe
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp
)
add_dependencies(test_exe test_target)
```

`main.cpp` is just:

```cpp
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I do a full rebuild, everything goes fine. But when I change `test.in`, run just `cmake.exe --build . --target all` only `test.h` is regenerated, but `main.cpp` is not recompiled. But when I run `cmake.exe --build . --target all` again(second time), `main.cpp` is recompiled and `test_exe` is relinked.

What do I wrong?

P.S. If I explicitly use `OBJECT_DEPENDS`, there is no issue, rebuild works fine, but the docs say it's not required anymore - https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/prop_sf/OBJECT_DEPENDS.html

Update:
I use Windows 10, CMake 3.19.2 and Ninja 1.10.2

**Solution:**
Use build directory inside your project dir, then there is no the problem. But if the build directory is outside of our project directory, then there is the problem.

Comment: Unrelated, but you can add targets directly in the `add_executable` command, you don't need that `add_dependencies`.

Comment: I foresaw responses about using `add_custom_target` and `add_dependencies`, so decided to use them. I tried all possible variants(without explicit dependencies, with them, with static lib). The only variant that worked was setting `OBJECT_DEPENDS`, but IMO it's outdated and unconvenient.

Comment: `add_dependencies` only gives *ordering* between the targets. For make executable **dependent** on the header, generated by the custom command, add that header to the `add_executable` call: `add_executable(test_exe ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.h)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev `test.h` is included in `main.cpp`. But I tried it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Probably need what CMake version, platform and generator being used.  Adding `COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.in" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.h` to your example along with `cmake_minimum_required` and `project` will recompile main.cpp on my windows machine. CMake version 3.18.2 using msbuild and Ninja.
Did you happen to consolidate multiple CMakeLists.txt files to minimize the question?

Comment: @mydisplayname updated the question. I use Windows 10, CMake 3.19.2 and Ninja 1.10.2

Comment: I believe but don't have time to look up -- CMake will only rebuild things that have changed as an optimization feature and cache the rest. Could have sworn I read that somewhere, hope it helps

Comment: @AdamCoville ok, I will try to google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as an answer to be able to show full example

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(example)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.h
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.in" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.h
    DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.in")

add_custom_target(test_target DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.h)

add_executable(test_exe
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp
)
add_dependencies(test_exe test_target)
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    printf("The value is %d\n", FOO);
    return 0;
}
```

`test.in`

```
#define FOO 4
```

This works on windows with CMake 3.19.2 and Ninja 1.10.2, one can change the `FOO` define in `test.in` after an initial build and see the resultant executable be rebuilt and see it's value changed.

The commands used to test

```
$ cmake -B build -G Ninja
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 11.0.0 with GNU-like command-line
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 11.0.0 with GNU-like command-line
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done                            
-- Build files have been written to: <some_path>
                                                      
$ cmake --build build                                 
[3/3] Linking CXX executable test_exe.exe             
                                                         
$ ./build/test_exe.exe                                
The value is 4                                        
                                                          
$ echo "#define FOO 3" > test.in                      
                                                      
$ cmake --build build                                 
[3/3] Linking CXX executable test_exe.exe             
                                                          
$ ./build/test_exe.exe                                
The value is 3
```

Comment: It seems that I found out the reason. If I call `cmake -B build -G Ninja` from console, everything works as expected and exactly as in your example, but if I generate it from QtCreator, the behavior is different - as I described it the question. Will dig in it. Thank you!

Comment: Wow! If you use build directory out of your project dir i.e. `cmake -B ..\build -G Ninja` then there is the issue, but if we use build directory inside the project, there is no issue. Is it a documented behavior? It's super strange.

Comment: >If you use build directory out of your project dir i.e. `cmake -B ..\build -G Ninja` then there is the issue,
I'm not able to reproduce that :(  it seems to handle incremental the same, inside or outside of the project directory.